# RxJava merge Observables but take result only from first

Tags: rx-java

I want to achive something like this: 
I have request that produces observable and also I have kind of a memory cache that can be a behavior subject. In my code I want to merge these two observables in a way, that if subject has some data I want to take these and don't start request observable. Can something like this be achived ?

At the moment I am doing something like this :

```
val resp = run { run(Task.GetMessages()) }

return InboxModel(news = Observable.merge(IoImplementation.cachedUserMessages(), resp).distinctUntilChanged())
```

but I don't think this is good

Comment: Will your cache and real-work observables each emit just one value?

Comment: well on the first run I get the data from the task, then I store them in memory cache, but I want the data to be emited only from the cache when the user rotates the screen and don't run the request. I should have mentioned I am on android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to try to find work in the cache observable and only if it's empty then try to do the real work. The `observable.switchIfEmpty(Observable)` operator should do what you need. If your cache observable is empty then it will subscribe to the real work observable.

```java
public void handleRequests(Observable<Request> requests) {
    requests.flatMap(Request r -> {
            String key = r.getSomeCacheKey();
            return getFromCache(key)
                .switchIfEmpty(doRealWork(r)
                    .doOnNext(saveToCache(key))
                );
        })
        .subscribe((String response) -> System.out::println);
}

// hashmap based cache may not be what you want but i'm 
// including it for completeness of example
Map<String, Observable<String>> cache = //...

Observable<String> getFromCache(String key) {
    return cache.get(key);
}

Action1<String> saveToCache(String key) {
    return (String response) -> cache.put(key, response);
}

Observable<String> doRealWork(Request someRequest) {
    // imagine real work here
    return Observable.just("some response");
}
```

Comment: thanks will give this a try, will keep you updated :)

Comment: well it seems to solve my problem, but I need to rethink my netwrok call operation somehow. Many thanks :) will mark this